# Can't change permissions to upload to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I read over two hours for solutions but now post my question.

I only need to update one single file on an AWS EC2 (centos server) and always have used FileZilla to do so but in the "/var/www/web/app" folder I am not allowed to upload any files.

I also am not allowed to change any folder permissions. I have only very little knowledge in using a terminal or putty and EC2. How can I upload this one single file to EC2? The online terminal which can be used in EC2 (under "Connect") does not open aswell. I start to pull my hair. I only need to upload this one file because I had to change one single line of code.

Comment: Please read some tutorials how to connect, such https://linuxacademy.com/howtoguides/posts/show/topic/17385-use-putty-to-access-ec2-linux-instances-via-ssh-from-windows, do you get the private key and username to connect?

Comment: I did this and also have converted the .pem file and used the private key generated from PuttyGen and tried to login. But it doesn't work. I can not connect with putty. it says "Server refused our key".

With FileZilla it works.

Comment: I searched a little and seems the filezilla is not really working with sudo users (you need to connect as centos, but copy files as root or some application user). At least I am not aware that it works with FileZilla.

Answer (score 0):

Your user has insufficient privileges to make filesystem changes.

You need to log in as the root user using the superuser account and password, which the owner of the EC2 hopefully has.

How did this code get onto the EC2 in the first place if it wasn't placed there by you?

Comment: it depends on what image is the instance based on, most of the images won't allow direct root logon. As well this guy apparently can't connect at all

Comment: @mcfinnigan A developer added the application on EC2 but now has not time for next few days but I need to have it done asap. Took us weeks to find the bug with Paypal SDK in a file and we finally now found it. 

So I changed the line of code in a php file (as the Paypal developers outlined) but now can not upload the file.

My account is a superuser account and I can login to the EC2 console but with the key pairs and username of the server it doesn't work to upload anything to this directory nor to change the permission via FileZilla.

Comment: @gusto2 I can connect properly to the EC2 instance and see all folders but I can not change the permissions in FileZilla.

Comment: @createawesomestuff what username is filezilla connecting as?  If you're superuser, you can simply run `chmod a+w /var/www/web/app` on the ec2, upload the file, then run `chmod a-w /var/www/web/app` afterwards to revert the permission change.

Comment: @createawesomestuff I assume the superuser is not root, usually it is another user with sudo capability (please confirm/deny)  imho the best option for you would be copying the files to the user's home and then use the ssh console (terminal) with sudo to copy the files where you need them

Comment: @mcfinnigan 
The username is "centos". But where to run this code you mention? I have 0 experience with SSH and EC2 or connection via Terminals

Comment: @mcfinnigan maybe some users still need write permisions to the app folder, with the commands the guy can screw more things than fixing it. Mainly if he is keen copying files direcly onto prod env :/

Comment: @createawesomestuff prepending *sudo* command will execute following commands in the 'root mode' so executing `sudo cp somefile /var/www/...` will make the cp (copy command) execute as superuser without any restrictions. However, I am not sure if the production is the best space to learn

Comment: @gusto2 from what I remember, `a` should leave  group and user rights unmolested.  `www` should own `/var/www` in any modern linux unless I'm mistaken.  Good call on sudo.

Comment: @mcfinnigan
I have connected via FileZilla but in FileZilla I can't see something like a command line. For Putty I tried the username "root" (AMI legacy, official AMI usernames) but it's not working.

Comment: @createawesomestuff check your filezillla setting what user you need to use, most of the centos images uses `centos` as username.

Comment: @createawesomestuff check your filezillla setting what user you need to use, most of the centos images uses `centos` as username.

Comment: @gusto2
I only had to remove one single line of code (4 words in the paypal payment php with very clear instructions) which was too much information and there fore blocked the payment flow. Because I don't know how to use github and putty doesn't work and all the developers are busy I am forced to change it myself. So yes, I am "keen" to do so as the platform is not live and still in testing phase. 

Since 1+ year developement time I always used "centos" and it's is still the same user name. But I always only had to use it to check code and work completion and never edited anything myself.

Comment: @createawesomestuff you need to 'only change a sigli line' but there are some security measures (you just hit) so only legit user could do that. This is according to the best practices.. Unfortunatelly you use FileZilla which apparently is really not the best tool here. (putty has to work, just you may not use it properly). O,k step by step - are you able copy the files on the centos home directory? (somewhere you should have write access).

Comment: @gusto2
I managed to connect via Putty. When I go to the folder "var/www/web/app/Services" there is a file called "PaypalPayments.php". Whenever I try to change it's permissions it says "not permitted".

I also listed the owner and the file shows "apache apache" instead of the user "centos" as the owner. But I also am not allowed to change the file.